# mojolicious auto-indent XML/HTML

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Can a Mojo tool auto-indent a string such the xml below?

```
<rpc-reply message-id="101" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"><data><native xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native"><version>17.1</version><hostname>R1</hostname></native></data></rpc-reply>
```

I have looked through the assocated Mojo packages, however, i cannot find this option.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with Mojolicious directly (or any Mojo::* modules I could find) however I know at least that [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) comes with the `xml_pp` executable.

Extracting the most basic code from that script gives you this...

```perl
use XML::Twig;

my $str = '<rpc-reply message-id="101" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"><data><native xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native"><version>17.1</version><hostname>R1</hostname></native></ data></rpc-reply>';

my $xt = XML::Twig->new(pretty_print => 'indented');

my $indented = $xt->parse($str)->sprint;

print $indented
```

Which outputs this...

```
<rpc-reply message-id="101" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <data>
    <native xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native">
      <version>17.1</version>
      <hostname>R1</hostname>
    </native>
  </data>
</rpc-reply>
```

Then you can output the string however you like.

Comment: Thanks, same as i found. Slightly annoying. When i render templates using Mojo::Template, for example, it'd be nice if i could make the result human readable in one package. I like to keep module depancany to a minimum. Seems odd they dont have this, there is a tool for nearly everyting else.